# find and replace words in files

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have two files: *file1* and *file2*.

Any match in *file2* should append "-W" to the word in file1.

File1:

```
Verb=Applaud,Beg,Deliver
Adjective=Bitter,Salty,Minty
Adverb=Quickly,Truthfully,Firmly
```

file2:

```
Gate
Salty
Explain
Quickly
Hook
Deliver
Earn
Jones
Applaud
Take
```

Output:

```
Verb=Applaud-W,Beg,Deliver-W
Adjective=Bitter,Salty-W,Minty
Adverb=Quickly-W,Truthfully,Firmly
```

Tried but not working and may take too long:

```
for i in `cat file2` ; do
nawk -v DEE="$i" '{gsub(DEE, DEE"-W")}1' file1 > newfile
mv newfile file1
done
```

Comment: we have many ideas, but we prefer to see yours beforehand. This is not a coding service

Comment: I'm sorry for the way I asked the question. I've been trying many things but 've been unable to come up with a reasonable solution or something close to that.

Comment: Where are you stuck, specifically? Have you come up with a plan? Even just describing the way you were thinking of approaching the problem would be good. Otherwise, it appears to us that you have made no effort to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
sed 's=^=s/\\b=;s=$=\\b/\&-W/g=' file2 | sed -f- file1
```

Output:

```
Verb=Applaud-W,Beg,Deliver-W
Adjective=Bitter,Salty-W,Minty
Adverb=Quickly-W,Truthfully,Firmly
```

To make changes in place:

```
sed 's=^=s/\\b=;s=$=\\b/\&-W/g=' file2 | sed --in-place -f- file1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach was not that bad but I would prefer `sed` here, since it has an in place option.

```
while read i
do
    sed -i "s/$i/$i-W/g" file1
done < file2
```

Comment: Note that using the `-i` flag that way only works with GNU sed, with other platforms or implementations it may not work as expected or at all

Answer (score 0):

Here is one using pure bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
    while read word
    do
        if [[ $line =~ $word ]]; then
            line="${line//$word/$word-W}"
        fi
    done < file2
    echo $line
done < file1
```

Answer (score 0):

An `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=",";RS="=|\n"}
     NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}
     {
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){
            $i=($i in a) ? $i"-W":$i
            }
        printf("%s%s",$0,FNR%2?"=":"\n")
    }'  file2 file1
```

**Results**

```
Verb=Applaud-W,Beg,Deliver-W
Adjective=Bitter,Salty-W,Minty
Adverb=Quickly-W,Truthfully,Firmly
```